# Tables' contours finding by OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to detect table's border by opencv, i choose the findContour function, here's the minimal demo.

```
def contour_proposal(rgb_matrix, weight_threshold, height_threshold):
    """
    :return: list of proposal region, each region is a tuple (ltx, lty, rbx, rby)
    """
    gray = cv.cvtColor(rgb_matrix, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    _, binary = cv.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY + cv.THRESH_OTSU)
    # binary = cv.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
    # binary = cv.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
    new_image_matrix, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(binary, cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    proposals = list(filter(
        lambda x: x[2] > weight_threshold and x[3] > height_threshold,
        map(cv.boundingRect, contours)
    ))

    res = []

    for p in proposals:
        x, y, w, h = p
        res.append((x, y, x+w, y+h))

    return res
```

---

### Here are two images for test

[[image]]
[[image]]

---

### Here are their finding result's visualization. I specific the contours result by blue rectangles.

[[image]]
[[image]]

---

The border of the table are correctly detected by findcontours in the second image while not in the first image. However, these two tables seem to have similar feature, both of them have the top and bottom borders and don't have the left and white borders. My question is, why is the first table cannot be detected while the second one can be detected? I've check the binary image of the first image, it's border information is not be abandoned.

So, how to retrieve the best detection results by opencv. Besides, the different kinds of threshold methods seems have no performance influence in this specific task(table detection), so which one should i choose?